# IsDefault and FocusScope recovery

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

my problem is that I have two buttons: "Backward" and "Forward".

```
  <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Backward"/>
            <Button Content="Forward" IsDefault="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Now when "Enter" button is clicked everything works fine. There is a possible flow that user clicks Backward button and then wants to use "Enter" to use "Forward" button. Problem is that "Backward" button is focused so "Backward" button handles all "Enters". So I tried to unfocus "Backward" button after click and still it doesn't work probably because StackPanel loses it's Focus Scope. What is the way of recovering Focus Scope to StackPanel?

In order words: 
After clicking backward button I want to set "Forward" button "IsDefaulted" property  to true. And I don't want to have whole StackPanel focused, I just want to change focus scope to be the focus scope where Forward button is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things you can do to achieve something like what you are looking for. However, these each affect the user experience in some way which may or may not be desirable.

- You could write a handler for the "Backward" button click which sets focus to the "Forward" button. The downside of this is that a user cannot choose the "Backward" button and keep pressing space to activate it multiple times.

  Xaml:

  ```
  <Button Content="Backward" Click="Button_Click" />
  <Button x:Name="ForwardButton" Content="Backward" />
  ```

  Code:

  ```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      ForwardButton.Focus();
  }
  ```
- Another option is to set your "Backward" to not be focusable. This means the button cannot be reached by the user at all using the keyboard, they are forced to use the mouse to activate it (making the application less accessible, probably bad).

  ```
  <Button Content="Backward" Focusable="False" />
  ```
- Alternatively, you could set your "Backward" button to not handle the return/enter key. It will still be focused when clicked on, and pressing space will still activate it after that point. However, pressing enter will be ignored, allowing your default button to pick it up. This would probably look confusing to the user though since the button they have focused is not the one being activated. In fact, I tested this and both buttons appeared to be visually focused at the same time after I clicked "Backward" (I am using the Aero theme).

  ```
  <Button Content="Backward" KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="False" />
  ```
- Yet another solution is to manually handle the key presses directly in your code behind using a `PreviewKeyDown` handler and perform the desired operations, as suggested in the answer from Toby Crawford. It requires more manual work, but allows you complete control over what happens. With this solution, you need to come up with some way to indicate to the user what is happening. Also, there would be some confusing flows such as the user tabbing to the "Backward" button, pressing enter, and having the "Forward" button activate. You would need to account for things like that.

Basically, it boils down to desired user experience. This is the sort of thing where you have to decide which user input flows are more important at the expense of having less important ones potentially not work as expected.

Focus management in WPF is complex <sup>[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx)</sup>. You can basically do whatever you want (whether it makes sense to the user or not), so it really helps to plan the overall focus flow of your application. You should consider reading up on [how focus and keyboard focus work in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but my problem is that I don't want to focus forward button, I want to back to scope where forward button is default button and is not focused, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: The [Focus Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) page describes how focus works and the various things you can do to change focus. It basically boils down to two options, either set the focus to null (clearing focus for the entire application until the user clicks something), or programmatically set it to an element somewhere. The button will always be the default button for as long as `IsDefault` is set to true, and will activate when enter is pressed _unless_ something is focused that handles the keypress so that the `AcessKeyManager` never informs the button.

Comment: I gave you thumbs up, the whole answer includes information I wanted to achieve, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the Backward button being pressed when it has Focus and Enter is pressed, you can intercept the Enter keypress and mark the event as handled.

For example:

```
<StackPanel PreviewKeyDown="HandleKeyPress">
    <Button x:Name="BackwardButton" Content="Backward" Click="GoBack" />
    <Button x:Name="ForwardButton" Content="Forward" Click="GoForward" />
</StackPanel>
```

With the following code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GoForward(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Forward");
    }

    private void GoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Backward");
    }

    private void HandleKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            this.ForwardButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            this.BackwardButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This means that whenever a child element of the StackPanel has focus and a key is pressed then you get a change to intercept the flow of that event.

In my example, if the key is Enter, then the Forward button will be clicked; and if the Back (backspace) key is pressed then the Back button will be clicked.

This means that even if keyboard focus is on the Backward button and you press enter; the GoForward() method will be invoked and not the GoBack() method.

The key thing is to handle a Preview___ event so that your code sees it before the button; and to ensure your code marks .Handled as true.  That way the button with focus will never see the event.

Comment: This is a decent solution, but keep in mind the implications of not allowing the button's [enter key handling code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,591) to run. It means it will not respect the `KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn` property, nor will it update its internal state. This may be fine for you, but it is good to understand the side effects. A tweak you could make is to raise the `OnKeyDown` event instead of the `Click` event on the button.

Comment: There are downsides to this approach from a user experience point of view that need to be considered also. For example, if I tab over to the "Backward" button and press enter, the "Forward" button would activate, given the way the code is currently written. You will need to consider things like that and potentially add some more complexity to the code.

Comment: Yea, this is one of the solutions I came up with earlier, but I don't like it. For example you focus Back button click enter and then it goes forward. It is a problem, that's why I didn't like this solution. Anyway thanks for answer